# output file only contains data from one iteration

Tags: python, xml, parsing, for-loop, elementtree

The script only gets weather information for one station. I'd like to get all the ones listed in the link and write the values to a file with the format in the script below.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

#import module to open urls
from urllib import urlopen

#import module to parse xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#settings
airport = 'KORF,KPHF,KRIC,KDCA,KIAD,KADW,KBWI,KACY,KPHL,KMDT,KPIT,KEWR,KJFK,KLGA,KBOS'

#open xml file
xml_link = urlopen('http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1&stationString=KORF,KPHF,KRIC,KDCA,KIAD,KADW,KBWI,KACY,KPHL,KMDT,KPIT,KEWR,KJFK,KLGA,KBOS')

#parse data and assign root to element tree module
tree = ET.parse(xml_link)
root = tree.getroot()

#search for data under <data> and <METAR> tags
data = root.findall('data/METAR')

for metar in data:
    raw_text = metar.find('raw_text').text
    station = metar.find('station_id').text
    category = metar.find('flight_category').text

    file = open('metar.txt', 'w')
    file.write("%s is now reporting %s condition:" % (station, category))
    file.write("\n%s" %raw_text)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Your code already _does_ iterate over all the entries. Thing is, it rewrites the file from scratch for each one. Open the file just once before the loop, write during the loop (as you already do), close it after the loop, and you'll be fine.

Comment: BTW, I'm inclined to close this one as "too local" -- it won't help anyone else who wants to get multiple values from an XML file, as that isn't where the problem is.

Comment: Just because he mis-diagnosed his programming problem, it doesn't mean his problem is too localized. Many people misunderstand how opening files works, and that could be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114396/get-all-values-from-xml-file#comment17829798_13114396), your problem is not how you are iterating over the XML values, but rather the fact that you are overwriting `metar.txt` each time through the loop.

You should instead open and close the file outside of the loop.  The `with` statement can help you here, taking care of the closing for you:

```
with open('metar.txt', 'w') as f:
    for metar in data:
        raw_text = metar.find('raw_text').text
        station = metar.find('station_id').text
        category = metar.find('flight_category').text

        f.write("%s is now reporting %s condition:" % (station, category))
        f.write("\n%s" %raw_text)
```

(You should also not be using `file` as the name of your file object, because `file` is a built-in Python type for file objects, which you will shadow if you do so.)